# PHP MySQL calculate sum as a time

Tags: php, mysql

My db has total_hours field i already setup it as a VARCHAR. I should want to calculate total hours how to do it.

example .. sum of 11.00, 6.00, 3.15, 1.45, 0.30, 8.45

Total hours output is 30.35

but it should be 31.15, please help me..

Comment: whats your code to calculate it ?

Comment: Why are you saving it in a `VARCHAR` instead of a `TIME` or similar? If you're using VARCHAR because you know it won't always be numeric in the future, any sum algorithm won't work later anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because 8.45 is actually 8:45 and your using decimal arithmetic to add them up. II'd add the hour values separately and minutes value separately and then join them in the code.

something like this:

```
$hours = array("11.00", "6.00", "3.15", "1.45", "0.30", "8.45");

foreach ($hours as $hour)
{
   $point_pos = strpos($hour, ".");
   $hour_value += substr($hour, 0, $point_pos);
   $min_value += substr($hour, $point_pos +1, $point_pos+2);

}
$hour_value += intval($min_value/60);
$min_value = $min_value%60;

echo $hour_value  . ":" . $min_value;
```

Edit: You could do the same in your MySQL query.

Comment: I used your example to solve the issue.. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. I just modified the code a little to make sure only 2 decimal points are picked up in case there is something like 8.456...n which I doubt there would be. But just in case... Perhaps you should update your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

This will split the times apart at the decimal point, and then add them using clock arithmetic.

```
SELECT CONCAT(hours + minutes DIV 60, '.', minutes % 60) AS total_time
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(total_hours, '.', 1)) AS hours,
           SUM(SUBTRING_INDEX(total_hours, '.', -1)) AS minutes
    FROM mytable) x
```

Comment: seeing the hoops you have to jump through will  hopefully lead the OP to the conclusion that storing the time like that was a bad idea- and changing the db would make life easier

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the minute values in terms of `100` and not in terms of `60`

Like you should  store follwing in the database:

```
11.00  --> 11.00
3.15   --> 3.25
8.45   --> 8.75
```

That way you could have avoided this.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:
you should have saved it as a decimal and just SELECT SUM(total_hours)

OR

Select total_hours FROM table_name

and just for loop it.

The Sum operator is already built into mysql but it doesnt convert from the varchar